# Can't use WiFi adaptor with airodump-ng on Kali Live

Tags: kali-linux, airodump-ng

I'm trying to use `airodump-ng` on Kali, but apparently the last version of the firmware of my wireless adapter is not working, so I need to delete it:

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin
```

And then restart the system...

The thing is, I'm on Kali Live, so I can't restart the system. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

The firmware should be loaded by the module `iwlwifi`. So removing it from the running system  and reinstalling would probably be the way to go.

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi
depmod
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Make sure that you have the old firmware available, otherwise it will of course not work.